# Trying to align to bottom of viewport inside svg

Tags: svg, vertical-alignment, codepen

In this codepen, I've thrown everything I could find at the svg rectangles and none of them want to budge (preserveAspectRatio, alignment-baseline, vertical-align) 
https://codepen.io/fvila/pen/aYbvrQ

```html
<div >
  <svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" class="demo bottom" alignment-baseline="baseline" preserveAspectRatio=“xMaxYMax slice”>
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25" transform="scale(1.23)" />
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25" transform="scale(1.23)" alignment-baseline="baseline" />
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25" transform="scale(1.23)"  style="vertical-align:bottom" />
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25"  transform="scale(1.23)" preserveAspectRatio=“xMaxYMax slice” />
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25" transform="scale(1.23)"  preserveAspectRatio=“xMaxYMax meet” />
  </svg>
</div>

<div  style="position:absolute; top:0; left:500px">
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" class="demo bottom" alignment-baseline="baseline" preserveAspectRatio=“xMaxYMax meet”>
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25" transform="scale(1.23)" />
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25" transform="scale(1.23)" alignment-baseline="baseline" />
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25"  transform="scale(1.23)" style="vertical-align:bottom" />
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25"   transform="scale(1.23)" preserveAspectRatio=“xMaxYMax slice” />
    <rect class="obj" width="53.25" height="53.25"   transform="scale(1.23)" preserveAspectRatio=“xMaxYMax meet” />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want the rects to be at the bottom modify their y and height attributes

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, but I was trying to avoid doing that. I added in the scale on purpose to show that tweaking the heights and y's wasn't an option if you have a lot of objects.

Comment: I've found a solution using Illustrator (Inkspace will work too, I guess): I pasted the paths I wanted into illustrator, scaled them, added a rect with the height of the viewport, grouped, then did a bottom align on all objects. Then export selection as svg. then open svg in text editor and copy/paste the group.  This solves my problem. You can view the result here: https://codepen.io/fvila/pen/zWYbMR. I'm leaving the question open for the moment in case someone comes up with a smarter answer.